# Step-wise output of Longest Common Sub-sequence program makes no sense to me

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am new to dynamic programming and coded a program to find longest common subsequence using dynamic programming however to understand DP better I thought it would be a good idea to print results in each if-else condition in my recursive function, however that output is making no sense to me.

For instance, the first output is "Now m and n both are 0", but why? Shouldn't it be "Last characters B and B are equal " ? I'm sure compiler is using some logic which I'm not aware of, but I really want to know what is actually happening!

[image: Output]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int lcs(char *X, char *Y, int m, int n)
{
    if (m == 0 || n == 0)
    {
        cout << " Now m and n both are 0" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (X[m - 1] == Y[n - 1])// last character same
    {
        cout << " Last characters " << X[m - 1] << " & " << Y[n - 1] << "are equal " << endl;
        return (1 + lcs(X, Y, m - 1, n - 1)); // add 1 + computer for rest
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Last characters " << X[m - 1] << " & " << Y[n - 1] << "are unequal " << endl;
        return max(lcs(X, Y, m, n - 1), lcs(X, Y, m - 1, n));
    }
}


int main()
{
    char X[] = "AGGTAB";
    char Y[] = "GXTXAYB";
    int m = sizeof(X)-1;
    int n = sizeof(Y)-1;

    cout << " LCS length is " << lcs(X, Y, m, n) << endl;

    int a;
    cin >> a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a break point in the beginning of the `lcs` function you'll see that indeed the first output is `Last characters B & Bare equal`.

I think the reason you're not seeing that in the terminal is because of line limitation in the output. If you need any help on tracing add comment and I'll edit my post to cover the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your Program is working correctly,although some problems are still there.

1)  Checking for `m` and `n` should be less than 0,not equal to it as it should go from `size_of_array - 1` to `0`.

2)Add a space after and before printing a value in `std::cout`.

For example, in your output : `Last characters G & Gare equal` should be  actually `Last characters G & G are equal`

3) It is NOT Dynamic Programming Implementation. This is brute force as you may know.